# iOS 7 UINavigationController Push animation shadow

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller

With iOS 7 a new push animation was created, which slides the pushed view controller on top of the hierarchy. But when the animation happens, iOS apparently does two things to modify the design of the top view controller:

A shadow is added:

[image: A shadow of view controller when animating]

And a light overlay over the bottom view controller:

[image: A light overlay]

In most applications this is not a problem. But, I am currently working on an application with pixel perfect design and I use view controllers with clear background. But this functionality remains the same, and the light overlay appears over the view controller. Because the background is a white gradient, this light overlay (on screenshot 2) is very visible and when the animation completes, it is removed without animation, which makes it very noticeable and annoying.

I am aware I can create custom animations and transitions, but I am wondering:

**Is there any way to remove (or modify) this light overlay and shadow, without having to create custom transitions?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Not without heavy modifications.

Comment: Did you try using iOS 7's custom view controller transition APIs? objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html

Comment: Well custom transitions were made with situations like these in mind so asking for a solution that is not the correct solution is somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most elegant solution, but I've seen people use `UIImage` animations to show what they want shown. So, you could:

Screenshot the incoming `UIViewController`

Animate the arrival of a `UIImageView`

Call `pushViewController:animated:`, passing `NO` for `animated:`

Remove the `UIImageView`

Again, a bit of a hack, but maybe it's the best solution for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try this proxy

```
[[UIImageView appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"_UIParallaxDimmingView"), nil] setAlpha:0.0f];
```

I don't know if Apple allows this or not because it uses a private API. Will update when app submitted.

Comment: This solution only works if you don't have any other image views in your navigation controller hierarchy... so, not super useful.

Comment: @patr1ck You can subclass UIImageView and use your subclass everywhere needed. Then you can specify this proxy only to Apple's UIImageView which won't apply to your subclass.

Comment: Did this get approved?